# Python config file for script

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7

I have a problem with reading config file from file.
It looks pretty basic but as I am new in python for I'm missing something.

Config file looks like this

```
CCWD_HOME=/batch/ccwd
#Temporary location for daemon job listing
CCWD_TEMP=/tmp
#Directory for job definitions
CCWD_PROD=/batch/PRD
```

The problem is that syntax of this file has to stay this way.
Assigning string to variable needs quota marks ("").
Is there any easy possible way to read variables from config file as above?
e.g. I have script

```
#!/bin/python
import conf
print CCWD_TEMP
```

And got this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./testconf", line 2, in <module>
    import conf
  File "/app/test/conf.py", line 6
    CCWD_HOME=/batch/ccwd
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to `import` the config file. But you can't do that:  `import` is for importing Python modules, so the file you import is expected to be valid Python, which `CCWD_HOME=/batch/ccwd` is not. That is what the syntax error means.

You can use the module `configparser` to read the file, but it requires the settings to be grouped in sections headed by a section name in square brackets, like this:

```
[MyStuff]
CCWD_HOME=/batch/ccwd
#Temporary location for daemon job listing
CCWD_TEMP=/tmp
#Directory for job definitions
CCWD_PROD=/batch/PRD
```

If you can't change the config file you will have to parse it yourself.

```
with open("./testconf") as configs:
    for config in configs:
        if config.startswith("#"):
            continue
        keyword, value = config.split("=")
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to execute your conf file as a python script. Instead, it would be better to write a simple parser of your config file and inport all config values into a dict like so:

```
conf = {} 
with open(r"PathToFile", "r") as f:
    for confline in f.readlines():
        if "=" in confline:
            conf[confline.partition("=")[0]] = confline.partition("=")[2]
```

output is

```
print(conf)
{'CCWD_PROD': '/batch/PRD', 'CCWD_HOME': '/batch/ccwd\n', 'CCWD_TEMP': '/tmp\n'}
```

Answer (score 0):

The directories need to be strings. You can achieve that by not importing the config file as module but open the file as text file  (for example by numpys loadtxt()). Afterwards you can read out the directories by carefully scanning the lines.

Comment: I know that but I'm looking for workaround because syntax of conf file must stay this way without qoutation marks

Answer (score 0):

Change it to the following:

```
CCWD_HOME="/batch/ccwd"
#Temporary location for daemon job listing
CCWD_TEMP="/tmp"
#Directory for job definitions
CCWD_PROD="/batch/PRD"
```

Since you have made conf.py a python file, it has to adhere to python standards. Hence, it has to be in above format

If you want it to be like this only, then you'll have to use it in a diff manner. Instead of importing it, read it as a file, extract the contents and then do the required operations. Following is the code for that:

```
>>> with open("a.txt") as f:
...     content = f.readlines()
... 
>>>
# you may also want to remove whitespace characters like `\n` at the end of each line
>>> content = dict(x.split("=") for x in content if "=" in x)
>>> content
{'CCWD_PROD': '/batch/PRDw\n', 'CWD_HOME': '/batch/ccwd\n', 'CCWD_TEMP': '/tmp\n'}
>>>
```